# create proc with exec as 'dbo' not working crossing databases?

Tags: sql-server

There is a stored procedure

```
use db1
go
create proc SP1
-- with execute as 'dbo'
as
-- complex code omitted for the question
exec db2.SP2
-- calls other stored procs of other databases too
```

UserA has only permission to `exec db1.dbo.SP1` and it got an error of no permission to `exec db2.SP2` and got the following error.

> The server principal "Domain\UserA" is not able to access teh database "db2" under the current security context.

I uncommented the line `-- with execute as 'dbo'` and the error message changed to

> The server principal "Domain\DBA" is not able to access teh database "db2" under the current security context.

DBA is sysadmin and it's associate to `dbo`. It should have all the permissions?

Comment: Why do you wrap db2.SP2 with SP1? `GRANT EXECUTE ON OBJECT::db2.SP2 TO UserA`

Comment: This is just an example, the SP1 is long and call a lot of procedures in other databases.